# How to convert number words to int (like three to 3) using Dart

Tags: dart

I want to convert number words (like one, two, three and so on) to int (like 1, 2, 3 etc) using Dart

Answer (score 1):

```
int convStrToInt(String str) {
    var list = [
        'zero', 
        'one', 
        'two', 
        'three', 
        'four',
        'five',
        'six',
        'seven',
        'eight',
        'nine',
        'ten',
    ];
    return list.indexOf(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to depend on machine learning library or pair every string with the respective number.

```
int convertStrToNum(String str) {
 var number = <String, num>{'one': 1, ...};
 return number[str];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, machine learning might be the fastest and best way to do  this, but I can't really help you there. So, here's an implementation that would work assuming the "number word" follows a certain format, up until 10. (You could implement a RegExp parser to make this easier, but that would get tricky).

```dart
int convStrToNum(String str) {
    var oneten = <String, num> {
        'one': 1, 
        'two': 2, 
        'three': 3, 
        'four': 4,
        'five': 5,
        'six': 6,
        'seven': 7,
        'eight': 8,
        'nine': 9,
        'ten': 10,
    }
    if (oneten.keys.contains(str)) {
        return oneten[str];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just pushed a repo addressing this issue. It's open to open to build upon so feel free to contribute, it would really help improve the package. Heres the link https://github.com/michaelessiet/wordstonumbers.dart